# android studio error: "URI is not registered" and "AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":..."

Tags: android, android-studio

I am a new to android studio, now I face a serious problem and none of my previous projects cannot open for the same problem.

First,I updated AS to its new version according to platform tips. Then I tried to open old projects developed on the previous version. No matter which one I chose, It stuck in the process "Building project Gradle info" and no more proceed. So I moved project gradle folder and files to a tmp folder and re-open the project (I searched this method through Stackover flow too~). "Building project Gradle info" sticking problem solved. But I met another problem shows as followed pic.
 [image: problem 1]
This error shows in all projects I opened through "moving Gradle files to another folder" process metioned above. And for the project I am working on rightnow, another problem shows at the same time, shows as followed. I think these two problems caused for same reason (since they came out at the same time). But I don't know the reason. I tried many solutions but none worked.
 [image: problem 2]

PS: I imported one of awesome-android-ui library to my working project (Thanks to Masabeef), including demo project in the imported files. And second error seems occured in the imported project. So if it possible I made some error library path in the import process. But I worked fine at the beginning when I finished imported.

Any help is very appreciated.Many Thanks~~

Comment: After re-recheck the setup after importing the library, I found this problem maybe caused for adding compile project(':MaterialDesign') to build.gradle (module: app). Some buildtype setup for Proguard may solve this problem. I am still try different ways. Some one can give me some more advises?

Comment: I commented the buildtypes section in library's build.gradle and the error is gone, Dont know whether it would affect the development when I use this library from my own app. Need more time to figure out it. At least I can proceed in my project now.